# How to define foreign key relationship in EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I am using EF Core 2.1 for my DAL. This is how my model looks like

One user can have only one role:

```
// Role entity - kind of master
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

// User entity - every user will have one role
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I was thinking/tried to define the relationship between these two entities:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
    builder.Property(x => x.RoleId).IsRequired(true);
    builder.Property(x => x.CreatedOn).IsRequired(true).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);

    // FK - throwing compile time error 
    builder.HasOne(x => x.Role).WithOne(y => y.RoleId);
}
```

How do I define this one user one role relation using EF Fluent API?

Thanks.

Attachment:-
[image]

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting??

Comment: @marc_s Error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ims.domain.model.User'

Comment: I don't think `builder.HasOne(x => x.Role).WithOne(y => y.RoleId);` is necessary as by convention you already stated that your User entity should have just one role when you added `public int RoleId { get; set; }` and `public virtual Role Role { get; set; }` properties. Remove that and I am certain your application will yield just that behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not only in the FK relationship configuration, you also have problem in the default value generation configuration for the `CreatedOn` column. So write your Entity Configuration as follows:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(u => u.UserId);
    builder.Property(u => u.CreatedOn).IsRequired(true).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

    // FK - configuraiton
    builder.HasOne(u => u.Role).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.RoleId).IsRequired(true);
}
```

Comment: Please check the attachment in the post. It generated 2 columns in User Table

Comment: my intent is define that Role entity is master & User is child

Comment: No still the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184917/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-kgn-web).

Answer (score 0):

One of the tenets Entity framework is built on is "Convention over configuration" and by convention, I don't think `builder.HasOne(x => x.Role).WithOne(y => y.RoleId);` is necessary as by convention you already stated that your User entity should have just one role when you added `public int RoleId { get; set; }` and `public virtual Role Role { get; set; }` properties. 
Remove that and I am certain your application will yield just that behaviour as stated in my comment above.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can add Users to Role like this

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

Then you will register like this

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
    builder.Property(x => x.RoleId).IsRequired(true);
    builder.Property(x => x.CreatedOn).IsRequired(true).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);


    builder.HasOne(x => x.Role).WithMany(y => y.Users);
}
```